# Load Google Maps + MarkerWithLabel together?

Tags: requirejs

Is anyone else using Google Maps + MarkerWithLabel + RequireJS? I basically want to see if it's possible to eliminate the extra http request for MarkerWithLabel and somehow optimize how everything is loaded and initialized.

Right now I'm loading the Google Maps library dynamically from within a Require module (I need this for dynamic params), but I can only get MarkerWithLabel working after Google Maps has been loaded. Ideally it would be great to either fetch them together or at the very least preload MarkerWithLabel and keep the Google Maps handle (URL) dynamic.

I'm considering 'Delayed Module Evaluation' if there's no way to consolidate Maps + MarkerWithLabel. I'm curious how others are approaching this.

http://blog.millermedeiros.com/requirejs-2-0-delayed-module-evaluation-and-google-maps/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [requirejs async plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins). Basically you should end-up with something like :

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        /* Bower Libraries */
        async: '../bower_components/requirejs-plugins/src/async',
        markerlabel: '../bower_components/gmaps-makerwithlabel/index',
...
```

and after that, you can shim it to make sure google maps loads first:

```
markerlabel: {
    deps: ['async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js&sensor=false']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this: https://github.com/lupugabriel1/gmaps-markerwithlabel-amd

Based on Google Maps MarkerWithLabel 1.1.9. This is basically a fork that adds src/markerwithlabel-amd.js.

This extension offers AMD support for Google Maps MarkerWithLabel utility library of Google Maps Javascript API v3. Also fixes the problem with requirejs optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for recommandation, that plugin was developed be me based on this need :)

Comment: Cool! I'm using it on a project, and it works great! thanks a lot.